# Sequence of functions versus sequence of *integrals* of functions: uniform convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, uniform-convergence

Supposedly there is a sequence $\{f_n\}$ that converges uniformly to $f$ on $[0, \infty)$ but
$$ \int_0^\infty f_n(x) \ dx \not \to \int_0^\infty f(x) \ dx . $$
I can't think of any sequence that behaves like this. I've tried the following sequences with the constant 0 function as the limit:

- $f_n(x) = \dfrac{\cos x}{n}$
- $g_n(x) = \dfrac{e^{-x}}{n}$

I've also thought about using something like cosine as the limit function but that seems like "cheating". Any hints or explicit examples?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1507431/let-f-n-be-a-sequence-of-continuous-real-valued-functions-on-0-infty

Comment: @user326159 That does seem to be a duplicate, but I don't understand what $\chi$ is suppose to be. If it is the Legendre chi function, what is the subscript in $\chi_{[1, n]}$? **EDIT**: I believe it is actually the indicator function.

Comment: As you said, it is the indicador function https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function

Comment: Let $f_n(x)=1/n$ for $x\in [n,2n]$ and $f_n(x)=0$ for $x\not\in [n,2n]$.